# google earth engine python API

Tags: python, map-function, google-earth-engine

I am trying to get the cloud scores for all the images of landsat 8 collected withing specified time frame in `google earth engine python API`.

Here is the code I used:

```
Landsat8_collection= ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR').\
filterBounds(LW).\
filterDate('2015-01-01','2020-12-20').\
select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2', ],['B3', 'B2','B1'])

def cloud(img):
    value=img.get('CLOUD_COVER')
    final=value.getInfo()
    return final

landsat_cloud=Landsat8_collection.map(cloud)
```

I got the error. Whats wrong with the code?

Comment: And what is "the error"?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use getInfo inside a mapped function.  If you want all the valuesas, for instance a list, use collection.aggregate_array('CLOUD_COVER')